# Jquery Accordion wont open after coming back to the page with angular routing

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I built a jquery accordion that works perfectly when first coming to the page, however, when I am rerouted to that page with angular the accordion will no longer expand to see its children. My strongest guess is that it has to do with needing to initialize the accordion in the document ready function.

ACCORDION CODE:

```
        <ul class="accordion">
            <li>
                <a id="portfolioId" class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Portfolio Name</a>
                <ul class="inner">
                    <li class="">
                        <a id="projectId" href="#" class="toggle">Project Name</a>
                        <ul class="inner">
                            <li>
                                <a id="designId" href="#" class="toggle">Design Name</a>
                                <ul class="inner">
                                    <li>
                                        <a id="designName" href="#" class="toggle designArea" style="background-image: unset !important;">Design Area</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

SCRIPT CODE:

```
$(document).on("click", ".toggle", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
        $this.next().removeClass('show');
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
    }
});
```

I am using angular repeats to populate the data and like I said I have zero issues with it when first coming to the page but if I navigate away then come back the script will not add .show back to the element to be expanded.

Any help would be so greatly appreciated!

Comment: When are you binding to the document ?

Comment: Hi Gaby,Im completely new to Angular so I dont think it is bound to the document. This is all the code related to the accordion that I have right now.

Comment: The `$(document).on("click",...` binds to the document, the question is when is that code run ?

Comment: Appreciate the clarification. I have tried that section of code at the bottom of my document ready function as well as right under that function. Neither work on the reload but both work when the page is first loaded.

Comment: A couple of questions, does it work if you leave again and come back a 3rd time ? Any errors in the debug tools console ?

Comment: Oddly enough it does work if I navigate away and come back a 3rd time! How weird! Do you know why and how to fix it by chance? Also there are no console errors right now.

Comment: right, so it is bound multiple times (*each time the page is visited*). added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some initial comments the fact that it works in 1st, 3rd (*odd times the page is visited*) implies that the click handler is bound again on each visit to the page.

So the second time the page is visited there are two click handlers and since what they do is toggle the accordion they cancel each other out. The first handler adds the `show` class and the second finds it and removes it.

On solution is to unbind the handler before rebinding. (*for such cases it is a good idea to namespace the event*)

So change the code to

```
$(document).off('click.accordion-toggle').on('click.accordion-toggle', '.toggle', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
        $this.next().removeClass('show');
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
    }
});
```

---

A better approach would be to do the unbinding (*`.off(...)`*) when you unload your component (*before changing page or other similar moment depending on what you app/page does*).

Comment: Thank you so much Gaby for helping me understand the problem and find a solution!!